# Try / Option with null

Tags: scala

I'm searching for a possiblity in scala to call a function and get an `Option` as result which is "None" iff either an Exception is raised when calling the method or the method return null. Otherwise the Option should have the value of the result.

I know that `Try` can be used for the first part, but I don't know how to handle the second part:

```
val result = Try(myFunction).toOption()
```

If the method now returns null (because it is not a scala function but a Java function), `result` is `Some(null)` instead of `None`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As I know there is only 1 method in scala standard library to convert `null` to `None` - `Option.apply(x)`, so you have to use it manually:

```
val result = Try(myFunction).toOption.flatMap{Option(_)}
// or
val result = Try(Option(myFunction)).toOption.flatten
```

You could create your own helper method like this:

```
implicit class NotNullOption[T](val t: Try[T]) extends AnyVal {
  def toNotNullOption = t.toOption.flatMap{Option(_)}
}

scala> Try(null: String).toNotNullOption
res0: Option[String] = None

scala> Try("a").toNotNullOption
res1: Option[String] = Some(a)
```

Comment: Can this be somehow wrapped so I don't have to write that many things?

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this:

```
val result = Try(myFunction).toOption.filter(_ != null)
```

which looks and feels better then `.flatten` or `.flatMap(Option(_))`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do pattern matching as:

```
val result = myFunction() match {
   case null => None
   case _    => Some(_)
}
```

but the answer of @senia looks more "scala style"